# How to find the name of a window

Tags: go, winapi

I'm working on a project in Go and I wanted to know if it was possible in C++ to use the function: `FindWindow`

For example:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "mywindow");
```

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs may be a good place to look?

Comment: C++ can call functions exported as `extern "C"` (which the Windows API does). So yes, you can call `FindWindowA` from C++. It's unclear to me, if that is the question you meant to ask. It's also unclear to me, what *problem* you are trying to solve, or how any of this relates to the Go language. It is clear to me, that attempting to find a window by window title only is usually not going to be part of any solution.

Comment: The code you provide indicates that you already know the name of the window. It's called "mywindow".

Comment: my goal is to read and write in memory.
That is to say to be able to modify a value of an .exe

Comment: Interesting. The question you asked though was how to find the name of a window.

Comment: If you want to know about doing things in C++, why is this question tagged with the Go tag instead of a C++ tag? (And if the project is written in Go, why do you care what C++ can or cannot do, for that matter?)

Answer (score 0):

FindWindowA is not implemented in golang's Windows package.  I don't like using this function to find processes anyways, I prefer to use [CreateToolHelp32Snapshot()](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#CreateToolhelp32Snapshot) or [EnumProcesses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses)

Both these functions are implemented by golang's Windows package and provide a way to loop through all the processes, once you have this list you can filter them by executable name.

Once you have located the correct process, the process id can be retrieved which you will need to pass to [OpenProcess()](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#OpenProcess).  OpenProcess is used to get a handle to the process with the required memory permissions you desire.

The windows package does not include WriteProcessMemory or ReadProcessMemory, you will need to either call it via a syscall or find another package such as [go-winapi](https://github.com/antonlahti/go-winapi) or [win](https://github.com/lxn/win)